# How to connect localwebserver from iPhone app

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, webserver, localhost

I have made an implementation of a  localhosted webserver which works fine . My webserver expososes an EJB interface which clients can connect to and make calls . I also created a Java client that connects to this ejb interface and calls the exposed API's . The webserver accepts a JSON object and can parse it to send back a JSON response . All this works fine and is 100% java (which i know).

Now i need to create an iPhone app client for/ to connect to this webserver and calls the exposed apis and exchange JSON objects . Since i am very very new to this I am not sure how does it work from within an iPhone app . How shld i connect to the webserver . I hosted it localally on my system .

So my question : How do i connect to this webserver to exchange JSON objects ? I searched on SO but couldnt find anything .

Comment: google has yielded gold http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: @CaptJak oh well this is good . thanks i am however much interested in the how to make the connection part to the server.

Comment: Check my answer, that should cover it. (BTW, the downvote was not I. When I do downvote, I leave a comment).

Comment: @CaptJak i know . its ok . Maybe the guy felt that i havent researched on the topic enough . However the thing is that i really really dont know Objective -C since its so different from other langauges that i have learnt over the years . thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are simple ways to connect to your server with an iOS app. You can do this using the NSURLRequest or NSURLConnection. It is simple to understand and implement.

[Apple docs on connecting using http and https](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html).

[NSURLRequest documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

[NSURLConnection tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/) (Contains multiple methods in this class).

Using these you can establish a connection to your server and make requests.

Now, since you did mention JSON, there is also a class for this called [JSONHTTPClient](http://www.jsonmodel.com/docs/Classes/JSONHTTPClient.html). I have used it with success several times to fetch and parse JSON. Here is also a [useful tutorial](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-json-by-using-data-models/) that can help you get started.

Another option that would work is using the dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: from the NSData class. It would be somthing like:

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourURLhere.com"]];
```

If your url returns JSON, you can just download and parse it using

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```